# NetBSD + openLDAP + SASL

Tags: openldap, sasl, netbsd

I try to set up a connection to a openLDAP server running on NetBSD 10 via TLS and SASL. When I try `ldapsreach -Y EXTERNAL`
I get
`ldapsearch: not compiled with SASL support`
and
`ldd /usr/bin/ldapsearch`
shows also no info about sasl-Libs. [This site](http://wiki.netbsd.org/projects/project/saslc_openldap/) says, that NetBSD has its own SASL-implementation for openLDAP, but I guess this will not fix the "not compiled whith SASL" thing (and until now, I'm unable to find the docs for this implementation). Any ideas, to get me back on track? Where to start?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out, that my version of openldap was in fact compiled without sasl support. Fixed that and it worked as expected.